# Не могу разобраться в разработке на ElectronJS + React/Vue/Angular

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js, angular, electron

Хочу написать десктоп приложение на js, и я очень запутался. Начал писать на electron + чистый js, но столкнулся с тем, что динамические элементы очень сложно реализовывать и, как я понял, React/Vue/Angular решают эту проблему. В приложении должны быть и вкладки, и выпадающие списки, и всякие формы. Какой фреймворк лучше подходит для этого? Какой проще для новичка в js? И правильно ли я понимаю, что GUI и сам код не особо то и связаны, а просто обмениваются данными между собой, и это то же самое, что бекенд и фронтенд? С чем мне стоит ознакомиться, чтобы получше разобраться в этом?

Заранее спасибо за советы

Comment: Про angular ничего не скажу. Из двух других предпочёл vue потому, что он показался гораздо удобнее. Попробуйте начать с него. Если что, то легко перескочите на react. Так-то они идейно идентичны.

Comment: Angular больше всего похож на подход работы с формами для десктопных приложений, например WinForms в C# или Swing в Java.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko За winforms опять ничего не скажу, wpf использовал. Cо swing-гом знакомился по толстой книжке. Как знатоку mvc по swing-у vue и react зашли на ура, в отличии от angulяра:)

Comment: Спасибо за советы, наверное попробую Vue

Answer (score 3):

Год назад перед разработкой приложения на Electron я сталкивался с похожими вопросами, не понятно было с чего начать.

Советую сперва рассмотреть различные примеры простых проектов  уровня "Hello world" на Github. Если вам необходимо уже начинать разработку, то советую отталкиваться от сборки, которую поддерживают на Github.

Прошлым летом я искал решение Nuxt + Electron и мне помог [этот шаблон](https://github.com/michalzaq12/electron-nuxt). Самое главное, чтобы сборка более менее активно поддерживалось и при возникающих проблемах можно было быстро найти нужный issue в репозитории.

По опыту скажу, что разработка на Electron принципиально сильно не отличается от привычного веб-приложения. Появляются лишь задачи, где необходимо разрабатывать методы для работы с файловой системой, с эвентами по открытию и закрытию приложения, управления меню декстопного приложения и т.д.

Допустим, если вы открыли какой-либо пункт в меню и он связан с методом во фреймворке Vue/React/Angular, то необходимо отправить запрос по IPC. Самое главное понимать, что у нас есть Main Proccess и Render Proccess, между которыми надо выстраивать клиент-серверное взаимодействие по IPC (см. рис. ниже). Главное это понимать архитектуру разрабатываемого приложения и стараться читать документацию Electron.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]